# Procedure returns data that satisfies both if and else conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a procedure like this

```sql
PROCEDURE FUNC(A VARCHAR2, B VARCHAR2, C VARCHAR2, CUR OUT) IS
BEGIN
  STR_1 := 'OPEN CUR FOR SELECT X, Y, Z FROM TABLE_T WHERE';
  STR_2 := 'TABLE_T.A=' || A;
  STR_3 := 'TABLE_T.B=' || B || ' AND TABLE_T.C=' || 'C';

  IF (A IS NOT NULL) THEN
    STR_4 = STR_1 || STR_2;
  ELSE
    STR_4 = STR_1 || STR_3;
  END IF;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE STR_4;
END FUNC;
```

This is not the exact procedure but a brief example of the same. When I run this procedure, I get results that satisfy both IF and ELSE condition ....But I want to execute either IF or ELSE statement

Where is the error??

Comment: Can you provide an example of parameter values that produce the undesired behavior?

Comment: @TheImpaler for all parameters as non null. I am getting results where A matches and B and C may/maynot match.....as well as A may/maynot match but B and C matches...In this case as A is not null so I should be getting rows whose A match and B and C may/maynot match only

Answer (score 1):

There are many errors:

1. You do not give a data type for the `CUR` argument.
2. You do not declare the `STR_1`, `STR_2`, `STR_3` or `STR_4` local variables.
3. You are building the SQL via string concatenation rather than using bind variables (assuming that you want to pass in the values of the input arguments rather than use the input variables as column names).
4. If you are passing values then you may find issues from having the function arguments having the same identifiers as the columns.
5. You filter on `TABLE_T.C='||'C'` which is the same as `C=C` or `1=1` and will always be true.
6. You use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` and the SQL you are trying to run is not either a complete SQL statement or a complete PL/SQL block.

One solution may be something like:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE FUNC(
  I_A   IN  TABLE_T.A%TYPE,
  I_B   IN  TABLE_T.B%TYPE,
  I_C   IN  TABLE_T.C%TYPE,
  O_CUR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
BEGIN
  IF i_a IS NOT NULL THEN
    OPEN o_cur FOR
      SELECT X, Y, Z
      FROM   TABLE_T
      WHERE  A = I_A;
  ELSE
    OPEN o_cur FOR
      SELECT X, Y, Z
      FROM   TABLE_T
      WHERE  B = I_B
      AND    C = I_C;
  END IF;
END FUNC;
/
```

Then, if you have the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_t(x,y,z,a,b,c) AS
SELECT 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 'xyz', 'xxx', 'yyy' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 'abc', 'aaa', 'bbb' FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
  x table_t.x%TYPE;
  y table_t.y%TYPE;
  z table_t.z%TYPE;
BEGIN
  func('xyz', NULL, NULL, v_cur);
  LOOP
    FETCH v_cur INTO x, y, z;
    EXIT WHEN v_cur%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(x ||', '|| y || ', ' || z);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> 1.1, 1.2, 1.3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=7953feac18782406ed63586dac2c230d)*

Comment: Hi @MT0 the solution doesn't work for me ...For example if I call FUNC('xyz'. __, __) the results returned by cursor has rows where A is 'xyz' as well as rows where A is not 'xyz' . Here __ denotes don't care.

Comment: @Hamsa I have updated the answer with an example of calling the procedure; my example works and I cannot replicate your issue. You need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71112604/edit) your question with a [MRE] that demonstrates the problem.